# How can I make a standalone app for one PDF book?

Tags: ipad, applications, pdf

I've seen many books or magazines as standalone apps. You download them from the app store as one single app. When you open it, it's just like reading a book or magazine and you can turn the page and scroll pages at the bottom. Very easy to use, not fancy but simple. You might not be able to zoom it, but on iPad it's fine.

There seems to be a standard framework or tools to allow easy creation for non-developers.

Any free tools out there that anyone might know?

Comment: I found myself one solution, not super easy but better than nothing. http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-libraries-for-quick-magazinebook-apps-with-pdf-files-or-images/

Comment: Does it really need to be an app rather than an iBook or just a plain PDF? May I ask why?

Comment: This is purely speculation on my part, but I suspect that apps as books with no significant added functionality might soon be banned from the App Store, in lieu of the iBook Store. Especially considering the release of the iBooks Author app.

Don't take this as fact, it's just an (in my mind) obvious-seeming idea.

Comment: Indeed, it's even in the app store review guidelines that apps that are books should be submitted to the iBookstore.